# Apache Access Log File Strange

Tags: apache, logging, server, apache2

I'm newbee on linux/server/apache..
I have an apache server runing on my machine, and I have a monitoring app "gotop" that I check from time to time. Even when there is a lot of traffic on my server the 4 core CPU are between 50~70 (not all of them at the same time, they switch between them..).
Today I checked gotop and saw all of them where about 100% with 85° temp!! 
I stoped the apache and the CPUs went down of course then went to the access.log and saw an local ip which is the one of my router 192.168.1.1 making infinite requests!
As you can see in the picture.
What is happening? why my router is requesting all this??
Thank you for your help =)
[image]

Comment: What's running on the router (intentional or otherwise) and making those requests?

Comment: Nothing.. it's my ISP router which  let me access to the internet..

Comment: Based on your logs it looks like there may be some kind of app running on your router that is making of proxying these requests, it might be worth checking if a router reboot helps in case your router has something unintended running within it.
Another route might be to edit your index.php to add some further diagnostic code outputting the user agent etc making the requests to help identify where they are coming from.

Comment: "add some further diagnostic code outputting the user agent etc" how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: A simple example might be to add error_log(print_r($_SERVER,true)) into the top of your index.php and then watch your apache error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a local machine which was downloading from the server.. Nevertheless, expecting another IP than the router one.